# Do I need to show a notification in response to a push notification if my site is foreground and focused?

Tags: web-push, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a Progressive Web App that uses Web Push Notifications and want to avoid showing notifications to users on either desktop or mobile that are already currently looking at my site.

I'm aware that my site must always show a notification when a push event is handled, but can I skip showing a notification if my site is open, in the foregoing and has focus?

Also is it possible to determine the above things when deciding whether to show a notification?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out you don't have to show a notification if your site is visible.

This can be implemented as follows:

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    return clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(clients => {
        for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; ++i) {
            if (clients[i].visibilityState === 'visible')
                return;  // there is a visible window
        }

        // continue with showing a notification
    });
});
```

Comment: I was using this successfully until recently; now I'm seeing odd `Failed to execute 'waitUntil' on 'ExtendableEvent': The event handler is already finished. - at clients.matchAll.then.clients` error, in addition to "This site has been updated in the background." notifications.

Comment: Can you file an issue on crbug.com with the code snippet you're using? That's fairly surprising!